# How to obtain this Facebook user id for the like button?

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-like

Referring to [the Open Graph protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph), I must implement this strange tag to my website in order to add a like-button for it.

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
```

`USER_ID` is supposed to be replaced by my actual user ID at Facebook. How do I safely obtain the correct user ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This user id can be found a few ways:
1) Go to http://graph.facebook.com/you_user_name and you will see JSON data with the id property.
2) Or go to your profile page and you will see a url like this http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=12345656. The number after id= is your user id.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a Facebook ID by doing this:
http://www.ehow.com/how_5753004_facebook-id.html

Basically, go to your photos and click on one. It will be in the URL bar under fbid.

Answer (score 0):

If you log onto facebook you will see uid=USER_ID in the URL for home, profile etc.

Comment: It was there when I looked, now it's gone, facebook is weird